# Не получается сложить JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list tr:even td").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
});
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  update_sum();
 });
});

function update_sum(){

var bonus = $('#sum_bonus').val();
var sum = 0;

$('input:checkbox').each(function (){
  if(this.checked){
    sum += (1*$(this).attr('data-sum'));
  }
});
 $("#total_sum").text(sum.toFixed(2));
 $("#bonus").text(sum + bonus);

 }
 </script>
```

`$("#bonus").text(sum + 20);` так получается сложить, а так
   `$("#bonus").text(sum + bonus );` а так не получается ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> $("#bonus").text(sum + bonus);
> ```

```
$("#bonus").text(sum + +bonus);
```

---

Хотя лучше вместо этого править здесь:

> ```
> var bonus = $('#sum_bonus').val();
> ```

```
var bonus = +$('#sum_bonus').val();
```

Comment: `var bonus = +$('#sum_bonus').val();`

Comment: @Igor, согласен, так лучше. Сам опубликуешь?

Comment: не, лучше добавить сюда как вариант

Comment: @Igor, дописал.